# Numerical method to integrate an exponentiated polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration, quadrature

Let $P_{n}$ be the set of polynomials of degree $n$. Then if $f \in P_{2n + 1}$ we can compute $$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx$$ precisely using $n$-point [Gauss-Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature).
I am interested in computing $$\log \int_{-1}^1 \exp [ \, f(x) \, ] dx$$where $f$ is a polynomial of known degree.
(Actually an even polynomial in my case.)
I'm hoping to compute this very precisely—i.e., I'd ideally like to recover the true answer up to machine precision.

I'm not an expert in this area, but my understanding is that the second integral is much harder to compute than the first.
Indeed, the simple case where $f(x) = -x^2$ is closely related to computing the log `erf` function, which is non-trivial.
Numerical [approximation schemes to the `erf` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations) seem diverse and complex to my untrained eye.

Are there any general principles for numerically computing the second integral above? Do any of the classic numerical techniques for the first integral extend to the second case?

**Similar question:** [How to numerically integrate expression using its log transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451771/how-to-numerically-integrate-expression-using-its-log-transform)

**Edit:** One obvious approach is to set $g(x) = exp(x)$ and then do Gauss-Legendre quadrature on $g(x)$ and take the logarithm of the result. My thought was that this would be numerically unstable for higher order polynomials. But maybe this can work just fine?

Comment: Not really that hard. You can basically do g(x) = exp[ f(x) ] then solve the integral, then apply log to the result. Did a quick code with 3 points (you can see more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature) and the difference with the real result is 0.0002 , if you need more precision, use more points.

Comment: Yes I thought of this but assumed it would be numerically unstable, especially for higher degree polynomials. Not true?

Comment: $f$ continuous means $e^f$ continuous and so bounded on a fixed interval, so it’s numerically stable and converges under most integration schemes. Convergence might not be super fast though.